# Unable to use exact_count_distinct BigQuery aggregate function

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting **Resources exceeded during query execution** error when I execute following query:

SELECT EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT( id ) FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.contents]

I used EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT aggregate function as COUNT([DISTINCT]) function gives only a statistical approximation.

Comment: Why are you doing that? There's only one row per id - so the number of rows in the table is that count.

Comment: Hey I have a BigQuery table in my own GCP project which has duplicate column values. So I was trying to replicate the problem with the same query in a public dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try below

for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM (
  SELECT id 
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.contents]
  GROUP BY id
)
```

for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) as cnt
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.contents`
```